# Too small Feynman diagram with tikz-feynman and size command doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman, tikz-feynman

First, I use

```
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]
```

and I found that the diagram is too small then I change to

```
\feynmandiagram[large, horizontal=a to b]
```

However, nothing is changed. I also try the code in the manual which compare 3 size (small, medium, and large) but I also get the same size for 3 diagrams.

Am I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style keys `small` and `large` only change the default separation between vertices, but they do *not* rescale the overall diagram, and this should work in all compilers. (Note: At the moment it does not, it only works with `lualatex`, see https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues/35#issuecomment-258429193. So either use `lualatex`, or the suggestion at the bottom of this post.)

As a result, if the position of vertices is specified explicitly,

```
\vertex (a) at (0, 1);
```

or if you specify the separation explicitly,

```
\vertex [right=1cm of b] (a);
```

then the `small` and `large` keys will have no effect on the placement of these.  Since you haven't provided the actual diagram you are drawing, then I'm only speculating that this is the reason.

If an overall scaling is really desired, it is possible to do so with the appropriate Ti*k*Z key, which can be passed to `\feynmandiagram`.  In particular, use:

```
\feynmandiagram[scale=2,transform shape][horizontal=a to b]
```

where the first set of brackets are the Ti*k*Z specific options, and the second set are the Ti*k*Z-Feynman options.  you can change the `2` to an appropriate value.

Comment: Not sure if this is actually a bug, but I reported it at https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues/35. [JP-Ellis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26980/jp-ellis), the package author, might chime in at some point.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion already. Both of them works with some comment. Your second option can adjust the size of diagram but not the size of label. The label for external particle is also bigger but the internal label is still small. So, I use the first option and it works very well. Thanks!!!

Comment: The keys `large` and `small` only modify the *default* distances between nodes.  If, for example, the position of the vertices is specified manually, then these keys will have no effect.  With your permission @TorbjørnT., I would like to amend your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @JP-Ellis Go right ahead and edit.